# watchguard openvpn verify error

Tags: openvpn, windows-10, watchguard

i've an Problem with an OpenVPN Connection, where i need al Little bit Help.

We've an Watchguard T15 by or Customer and he will connect his Noteboot by VPN to his network.

I've installed the actually Version of OpenVPN on his computer an imported the config File, i've downloaded from the Watchguard.

If i try to connect, i become the following error message:

```
Thu Jan 23 11:52:45 2020 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]STATIC_IP:PORT, 
sid=82f4374d c78f75b5
Thu Jan 23 11:52:45 2020 WARNING: this configuration may cache passwords in memory -- use the auth-nocache option to prevent this
Thu Jan 23 11:52:46 2020 VERIFY ERROR: depth=0, error=unable to get local issuer certificate: O=WatchGuard_Technologies, OU=Fireware, CN=Fireware SSLVPN Server
Thu Jan 23 11:52:46 2020 OpenSSL: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
Thu Jan 23 11:52:46 2020 TLS_ERROR: BIO read tls_read_plaintext error
Thu Jan 23 11:52:46 2020 TLS Error: TLS object -> incoming plaintext read error
Thu Jan 23 11:52:46 2020 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
```

Now comes the Joke. Onto my main pc can i connect to the Customer Network with the same Confic and same Logindata Successfully. 
I've try to use an older Version on the Customer Notebook too. 
In both cases the is Windows 10 V1909 installed. 
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome, I'm new here too!

That looks like a certificate error - I've only ever seen those when upgrading a site's Firebox to a new device, but it seems it can also crop up with public certificates. If you have a public certificate, switch to a self signed, save the config then switch back. If you don't, then what do you get when you try the WatchGuard SSL client (https://(his address)/sslvpn.html)?